# A QLineEdit with a QCompleter won't show the QCompleter's popup menu with an empty text field

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a `QLineEdit`, with a `QCompleter` object associated to it. If the user enters at least one character, the popup menu from the `QCompleter` is shown, but when the user deletes the last character (thus leaving the field empty) the popup disappears. Is there any way to make it show even when the `QLineEdit`'s text is empty?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should be able to force completer's popup window to get shown once your line edit text is erased by using [QCompleter::complete](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtextended4.4/qcompleter.html#complete) slot:

```
lineEdit->completer()->complete();
```

Here's how you can do it:

- define textChanged slot for your lineedit;
- override customEvent method for your window;
- in the textChanged slot send user event to the window whenever
  lineedit's text has zero length;
- in the customEvent method show completer whenever user event is received;

Below is an example:

mainwindow.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void customEvent(QEvent * event);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_lineEdit_textChanged(QString );
};
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
class CompleteEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    CompleteEvent(QLineEdit *lineEdit) : QEvent(QEvent::User), m_lineEdit(lineEdit) { }

    void complete()
    {
        m_lineEdit->completer()->complete();
    }

private:
    QLineEdit *m_lineEdit;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QStringList wordList;
    wordList << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four";

    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    lineEdit->setGeometry(20, 20, 200, 30);
    connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), SLOT(on_lineEdit_textChanged(QString )));

    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
    lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::customEvent(QEvent * event)
{
    QMainWindow::customEvent(event);
    if (event->type()==QEvent::User)
        ((CompleteEvent*)event)->complete();
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(QString text)
{
    if (text.length()==0)
        QApplication::postEvent(this, new CompleteEvent((QLineEdit*)sender()));
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I was trying to do something similar with a QTimer::singleShot, but for some reason the it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution based on serge_gubenko's answer. This class uses QStringListModel, but it can be easily replaced with any other model.

`Completer_line_edit.h`

```
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QStringListModel>
#include <QTimer>

/*! Line edit widget with auto completion based on QStringListModel.
  Modified behaviour: completion list will appear even when contents of
  line edit is empty. Full list of options will be showed when line edit
  has focus and is empty.
  */
class Completer_line_edit : public QLineEdit {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Completer_line_edit(QWidget *parent = 0);

  //! Set list of options used for copmletion.
  inline void set_list(QStringList list) { model.setStringList(list); }

private:
  QStringListModel model;
  void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e);
  void customEvent(QEvent* e);
  QTimer timer;

private slots:
  void slot_text_edited();
  void slot_call_popup();

};
```

`Completer_line_edit.cpp`

```
#include "Completer_line_edit.h"
#include <QCompleter>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QApplication>

Completer_line_edit::Completer_line_edit(QWidget *parent) :
  QLineEdit(parent)
{
  setCompleter(new QCompleter());
  completer()->setModel(&model);
  completer()->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
  completer()->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(slot_text_edited()));
}

void Completer_line_edit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e) {
  QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
  // force completion when line edit is focued in
  completer()->complete();
}

void Completer_line_edit::slot_text_edited() {
  qDebug() << "text edited";
  // force to show all items when text is empty
  completer()->setCompletionMode(text().isEmpty()? QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion: QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
  if (text().isEmpty()) {
    // completion list will be hidden now; we will show it again after a delay
    timer.singleShot(100, this, SLOT(slot_call_popup()));
  }
}

void Completer_line_edit::slot_call_popup() {
  // apparently, complete() works only in event handler
  QApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::User));
}

void Completer_line_edit::customEvent(QEvent *e) {
  QLineEdit::customEvent(e);
  // force completion after text is deleted
  completer()->complete();
}
```