# Use Qt QCompleter to start matching at a different column

Tags: qt, autocomplete

I would like to autocomplete text of the second token of an input string.  For example:

>w String_to_match

The w command is not to be used for lookup, but the string_to_match is.  I have tried using SetCompletionColumn to 2 and 3, but if it is not 0, no popup list appears no matter what I type.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `QCompleter::setCompletionPrefix` to set a string that should be used for searching. Every time the user changes the string, remove '>w' from the string and pass the rest to  `QCompleter::setCompletionPrefix`.

Comment: I am using a QLineEdit control.  When I do this, the behavior doesn't change. The first column still brings up the popup and when I type ">w " nothing pops up.

Comment: Your solution is basically correct.  However, this has to happen in response to an event as described in:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857180/a-qlineedit-with-a-qcompleter-won-show-the-completers-popup-menu-with-an-empty